# Return length of NVARCHAR or VARCHAR variable definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've declared a variable in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @CurrentChunk NVARCHAR(250)
```

I would like to use the length of the variable, i.e. `250`, later in my sp for computational purposes, and I want to keep my code as [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible.

Here's my code (assume `@Narrative` is a param to the SP):

```
DECLARE @ChunkSizeCharacters INT, 
        @NumChunks INT, 
        @LoopIndex INT, 
        @CurrentChunk NVARCHAR(250)

SET @ChunkSizeCharacters = 250 -- HERE'S WHERE I WANT THE LENGTH OF @CurrentChunk
SET @NumChunks = CEILING((LEN(@Narrative) * 1.0)/@ChunkSizeCharacters)
SET @LoopIndex = 0;

WHILE (@LoopIndex < @NumChunks)
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentChunk = SUBSTRING(@Narrative, 
            ((@LoopIndex * @ChunkSizeCharacters) + 1), @ChunkSizeCharacters)

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Chunks] ([Chunk]) VALUES (@CurrentChunk)
        SET @LoopIndex = @LoopIndex + 1
    END
```

Is there a way to ascertain the length of an `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` variable *definition* (please read carefully -- I'm not looking for `LEN()`)?

Comment: I suspect with some explanation of what you are trying to do you get rid of the loop here and greatly simplify this.

Comment: The loop is there just to substantiate the need for the length of `@CurrentChunk`, i.e. to show that I've actually contrived a computation that uses that value.

Comment: uuuhhh ok. That didn't mean much of anything to me but whatever. I just don't see a need for a loop from what you posted. Seems like a tally table could do this in a single pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the MaxLength variant property returns the value you're looking for.

```
 DECLARE @Banana varchar(255) = 'This banana'

 SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@Banana, 'MaxLength')
```

Returns 255.

Comment: Wow, that is sneaky. I love it!

Comment: A couple things here though -- in testing, it returns double the length for `NVARCHAR` since under the hood two bytes are used for each char.  Also, if the variable is empty, it returns `NULL`, so to use this method, you have to put data in in first, even if it's an empty string (just like you have in your example with `This banana`).

Comment: Shame about the `N` mismatch -- although you can compensate for this by checking the `BaseType` property, that makes the expression unwieldy. But speaking of that, this actually allows you to determine the type of a T-SQL expression: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(1.0 * 2, 'BaseType')` yields `numeric`. Since the T-SQL rules for conversion are positively arcane, this can be a real time saver.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely one for the personal tool kit.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I hadn't actually noticed that NVARCHAR is twice the length, but that makes sense. For the null issue, you could use `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ISNULL(@Banana,''), 'MaxLength')` instead, to avoid having to set it as an empty string.

Comment: @JamesMacGilp -- Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind overwriting the variable (and if you do, you can assign it to a temp `NVARCHAR(MAX)`):

```
SELECT @CurrentChunk = REPLICATE(0, 8000);
SELECT @ChunkSizeCharacters = LEN(@CurrentChunk);
```

This trick does not and cannot work for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but that's presumably no problem, given it's enormous maximum size.

Unfortunately T-SQL has nothing in the way of metadata properties for variables. Even determining the type of an expression is a chore.

Comment: Unnecessarily clever, as it turns out. [`SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178550) for the win!

Comment: Hmm...after testing, it's more of a toss-up between yours and `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`.  See my comments under that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the value returned by that SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY statement doesn't select into a plain, predefined variable. In the end, I used:

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(400), @TextLen INT
SELECT @TextLen = CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ISNULL(@Text, ''), 'MaxLength') AS INT)
```

Works like a charm for me!